# Combining 3 channel numpy array to form an rgb image

Tags: python, numpy, rgb, numpy-ndarray

I was trying to combine 3 gray scale images into a single overlapping image with three different colors for each.
For that, I added each into a 3 channel numpy array.
But when plotting with im.show I don't get a colourful image. Till adding 2nd channel it works, but when I add the third channel, it doesn't work. The final image has only red and blue colour.
It is supposed to be red, green and blue for corresponding to  the overlapping images.

Why would it be?

```
    image1 = Image.open("E:/imaging/04102022_Bronze/Copper_4_2/10.tif") #openingimage1
    image1_norm =(np.array(image1)-np.array(image1).min() ) / (np.array(image1).max() - 
    np.array(image1).min()) #normalisingimage1

    image2 = Image.open("E:/imaging/04102022_Bronze/Oxygen_1_2/10.tif")#openingimage2
    image2_norm = (np.array(image2)-np.array(image2).min()) / (np.array(image2).max() - 
    np.array(image2).min())#normalisingimage2


    image3 = Image.open("E:/imaging/04102022_Bronze/Oxygen_1_2/10.tif")#openingimage3
    image3_norm = (np.array(image3)-np.array(image3).min()) / (np.array(image3).max() - 
    np.array(image3).min())#normalisingimage3

    im=np.array(image2)
    new_image = np.zeros(im.shape + (3,)) #creating an empty 3 channel numpy array .shape of this
                                       array is (255, 1024, 3)


    new_image[:,:,0] = image1_norm #adding the three images into three channels
    new_image[:,:,1] = image2_norm
    new_image[:,:,2] = image3_norm


    new_image1=new_image*255.999
    new_image2= new_image1.astype(np.uint8)
    final_image=final_image=Image.fromarray(new_image2, mode='RGB')
```

Comment: Where does the Image class come from? Are you using PIL?

Answer (score 1):

A few possible issues...

---

When you open an image in PIL, if you want to be sure it is single-channel greyscale, and not accidentally 3-channel RGB, or a palette image, force it to greyscale:

```
im = Image.open('image.png').convert('L')
```

---

Try not to repeat complicated calculations or expressions several times - it just makes for a maintenance nightmare. Maybe use a function instead:

```
def normalize(im):
   # Normalise image to range 0..1
   min, max = im.min(), im.max()
   return (im.astype(float)-min)/(max-min)
```

---

You can use Numpy's `dstack()` to merge channels - it means *"depth"*-stack, as opposed to `np.vstack()` which stacks images vertically above/below each other and `np.hstack()` which stacks images side-by-side horizontally. It is a lot simpler than creating an image of the right size and individually pushing each channel into it.

```
result = np.dstack((im1, im2, im3))
```

---

That would make the overall code more like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def normalize(im):
   # Normalise image to range 0..1
    min, max = im.min(), im.max()
    return (im.astype(float)-min)/(max-min)

# Load images as single channel Numpy arrays
im1 = np.array(Image.open('ch1.png').convert('L'))
im2 = np.array(Image.open('ch2.png').convert('L'))
im3 = np.array(Image.open('ch3.png').convert('L'))

# Normalize and scale
n1 = normalize(im1) * 255.999
n2 = normalize(im2) * 255.999
n3 = normalize(im3) * 255.999

# Merge channels to RGB
result = np.dstack((n1,n2,n3))
result = Image.fromarray(result.astype(np.uint8))
result.save('result.png')
```

That makes these three input images:

[image]

into this merged image:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks, This worked. But I couldn't add legends so that I know what colour in the combined picture corresponds to which element(in my case).

Comment: Your question doesn't mention any legends. If you have a question about legends, please just ask a new question, and be sure to put your existing, latest/greatest code in there and clearly show what you have and what you expect to get. Thanks and good luck.

Comment: I have a question, why do we need to normalize the single channel and scale it? Why not just just combine 3 channel right away